# Is there a way to show transactions in console as soon as they are logged in a log table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table were processes are logged to and I want to create a console app that will loop and update the console as soon as the messages are written to the table.

The end result will be me looking at the console instead of querying the database.

I have a query that can pull the data and display, however I am looking for best practice/better solution as I feel mine is not up to standard

```
string ConnectionString = "connectionstring here";

string TableName = "table name here";

while (true)
{

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select LogDate, Message from " + TableName + " where convert(date, logdate, 103) = convert(date, getdate(), 103) order by logdate;", myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["LogDate"].ToString() + " -> " +             
        myReader["Message"].ToString());
                //Thread.Sleep(200);
    }

    myConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: You might want to consider posting questions about code quality of working code over the on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

3 things I find worth mentioning:

- Careful when building dynamic SQL by concatenating uncontrolled values. What happens if your `TableName` has a space in the middle (or worse, an SQL command like `TableName; DECLARE @CurrentLogin VARCHAR(100) = SYSTEM_USER; EXEC('DROP LOGIN ' + @CurrentLogin);`, do not execute!). Since you are dynamically changing the table, you can't parametrize this query, although there are some things you can to do reduce the risk of injection like making sure the `TableName` variable is less than X characters (usually 20 is enough), and doesn't contain spaces, semicolons or critical SQL words like `EXEC` or `DROP`.
- You are selecting and filtering specific columns, so this query won't work on most tables, just the ones that have these columns. You should consider removing the dynamic table parameter and use a `Switch` instead, allowing only the tables you want to query to be queried. This will make your queries limited but safer.
- Your filter is converting a table column (`logdate`) before doing a comparison to a constant (`getdate()`), this will make the index on `logdate` (if any) be inapplicable. I believe you want to see records of the current day, so you are making the comparison on the date code `103` (`yyyy-MM-dd`). You should avoid converting the table value and use a double filter instead, assuming that `logdate` is `DATETIME`. If `logdate` can't be on higher date than today you can skip the 2nd check:

  ```
  WHERE
      logdate >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND
      logdate < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + 1)
  ORDER BY
      logdate
  ```

> The end result will be me looking at the console instead of querying
>   the database.

The console will query the database for you, you are just changing the user interface.

If you have many console logs, you can do a dynamic filtering by `datetime` instead of querying all the current date every time. So each query will bring records from the last `datetime` you queried, thus bringing all *new* records. You can do this by adding a full `datetime` parameter, only retrieving records higher than the previous one and storing the current datetime on this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a pull model and repeatedly querying the data even if there was no change, you could use a SqlDependency that notifies your application when a change occurs. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) contains an overview and a sample.

One thing to note though is that `SqlDependency` objects were built with server applications in mind. It is not meant to be rolled out to lots of clients listening for changes. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) for additional information.